# Kubernetes Apache Ignite Random-LRU eviction algorithm

Tags: ignite, kubernetes-helm

My project have setup an Stateless Apache Ignite cluster in Kubernetes. During performance testing, the memory for each Apache Ignite pods has reach its memory limit and slows down the application performance.

After doing some reading, we discover that there is no any eviction policy implemented by default and there is actually a section from documentation that suggesting that we can implement a eviction for off-heap eviction.
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/evictions#section-random-lru

However, we face a problem on implementing the policy because we are using helm chart and it does not provide much option for us to modify the configuration xml.
https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/ignite

Help would very much appreciated

Comment: I think that you should enable persistence, and give your POD smaller amount of memory so that data region will be smaller.

Comment: Enabling persistence is not allowed in my case. From your suggestion, should i give server POD or client POD smaller amount of memory? Because the client is actually a SpringBoot application that I cannot change the amount of memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see `Ignite` `XML` configuration is [hard-coded](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/ignite/templates/configmap.yaml) into this `Helm` chart. Unfortunately expiry policy is not configurable through it. From my point of view the only option here is to contribute to this chart or just adjust it for your local use. Or you could seek for some other way to do `k8s` deployment automation.

Comment: thank you for your answer, my team and I have decide to adjust the chart